# Angular $cookies not persisting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, interceptor, angular-resource

I'm using angular $resource to access an API. In this particular case with a custom login action, in order to login a user.

In order to save the token provided by the API after authentication, I'm attaching an interceptor to the custom login action, which simply saves the token to a cookie, via $cookies.

I'm using an interceptor since I'll be required to save and update that cookie from other parts of the app.

The problem is that the cookie does not seem to persist.

If I check the value just after saving I can confirm it's there, but as soon my $location is changed (like when rendering the home page after login), the cookie disappears.

Any ideas?

Thanks, D.

Here is my Login Service, which uses a custom login action and an interceptor

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    //Login Service
    // Authenticates a user
    angular
    .module('console')
    .factory('LoginService', LoginService);    
        LoginService.$inject = ['$resource', 'Config', 'UserInfoInterceptor'];

            function LoginService($resource, Config, UserInfoInterceptor) {

                return $resource(Config.api_url + '/auth/', {},
                    {
                        login: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: Config.api_url + '/auth/login',
                        data: {type: "passwd"},
                        interceptor: UserInfoInterceptor,
                        headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json",
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    }
                }
            });
    }
})();
```

And here is the interceptor (That console.log there, actually writes the cookie value), but it gets lost right after going to other location.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('console')
    .factory('UserInfoInterceptor', UserInfoInterceptor);
    UserInfoInterceptor.$inject = ['$resource', 'Config', '$q', '$location', '$cookies'];


    function UserInfoInterceptor($resource, Config, $q, $location, $cookies) {    

        return {

                // Save the received token 
                'response': function (response) {

                    var now = new Date();
                    // this will set the expiration to 30 days
                    var exp = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, now.getDate());

                    // Set the cookie
                    $cookies.put('token', response.data.token, {expires: exp});

                    //This actually works!!
                    console.log($cookies.get('token'));

                    return response;
                },

                // Whatever is the failure, throw the user to the login page
                'responseError': function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            };    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too late but this fix might help others as well i think.

I tried to set the cookie path in `$cookiesProvider` as shown below,

```
xxApp.config(['$cookiesProvider', function ($cookiesProvider) {
     $cookiesProvider.defaults.path = '/'; 
}]);
```

Comment: it's never too late